# "to keep them/to be kept at the required temperature"

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

> 1. Perishable foodstuffs are kept in refrigerated cabinets to keep them  at the required temperature.
> 2. Perishable foodstuffs are kept  in refrigerated cabinets
>      to be kept at the required temperature.

Which is better, active or passive?

Answer (score 1):

> Perishable foodstuffs are kept in refrigerated cabinets **to keep** them at the required temperature.

This is a perfect sentence—the one you should go with. The part *perishable foodstuffs are kept in refrigerated cabinets* is the statement and the second part *to keep them at the required temperature* is the reason for that statement. Paraphrased a little bit, what this sentence really says is that the reason perishable foodstuffs are kept in refrigerated cabinets is to keep them at the required temperature. In other words, the whole reason you keep them in refrigerated cabinets is to keep them at the required temperature. So, that's, I think, pretty straightforward logic.

> Perishable foodstuffs are kept in refrigerated cabinets **to be kept** at the required temperature.

If we now try to put this sentence through the same logic as above, we will end up with something that might sound a little bit nonsensical. The reason perishable foodstuffs are kept in refrigerated cabinets is to be kept at the required temperature. The phrase *to be kept* has a sense of something that has a possibility of happening in the future. So, this sounds like you keep perishable foodstuffs in refrigerated cabinets for the reason that they will likely be kept there at the required temperature in the future. That just doesn't sound right and obviously is not what you intend to say.

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence is fine.

The second sentence is awkward, better might be

> Perishable foodstuffs are to be kept at the required temperature in refrigerated cabinets.